# Beginning with assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm reading a book about assembly and I'm trying to learn a little bit about this language. I got some code to understand what he's been doing, but I'm having trouble.

Could somebody please explain what makes the code below?

```
push ebp           //put in top the stack, right?
mov ebp, esp       //mov the value esp to ebp
push ecx           // ok...
mov eax, [ebp+8]   //What's ebp+8? 
add eax, [ebp+0Ch] //What's ebp+0Ch?  
add eax, [ebp+10h] //What's ebp+10h
mov [ebp-4], eax   //What's ebp-4
mov eax, [ebp-4]
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
retn
```

In summary: what makes this piece of code?
I don't understand anything of it.

Comment: Stack is ordinary memory too. So to manipulate value in stack, you can address it with [esp] too. Upon entering your procedure the [esp] points to return address (top of the stack). `push ebp` will store old `ebp` value, [esp] now points to old ebp, and [esp+4] is return address (stack "grows" downward, `push dword value` doing `esp -= 4`). Then `[esp+8]` is dword pushed by the caller on stack before calling you (first argument). When you copy `esp` into `ebp`, you can now address it with `[ebp+8]` too. Run this in debugger, point memory window to the `esp` area, watch the values there then.

Comment: what makes this code what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to explaining the code, the function of the `PUSH` OpCode has to be defined:

> It decrements the stack pointer and then stores the source operand on the top of the stack.

So, firstly, the following two lines create a standard *Stack Frame*. They assign `EBP` to the current location of the *Stack Pointer(`ESP`)*, which is useful for accessing local variables on the stack by referencing them relative to `EBP`(the so-called *Base-Pointer*).

```
push ebp           //put in top the stack, right?
mov ebp, esp       //mov the value esp to ebp
```

Now `EBP` points to the current stack position.

The following line  pushes `ECX` to the stack(`ESP`) - decreasing `ESP` by 4. `EBP` stays the same.

```
push ecx           // ok...
```

Because `EBP` still points to the stack position when calling this function minus 4 (see above), the following line

```
mov eax, [ebp+8]   //What's ebp+8?
```

moves the first parameter `EBP+8` to `EAX`.

Remember:

- On entry             : ESP = x    ( = return address pushed there by `CALL`)
- After `PUSH EBP`     : ESP = x-4  ( = return address is at ESP+4)
- Then `EBP` is set to : ESP = x-4  ( EBP = ESP = x-4 (now points to the old value of EBP))
- So the *return address* is located at `EBP+4` and the first parameter is located at `EBP+8`(32-bit = 4 byte).

And so on like this:

```
add eax, [ebp+0Ch] //What's ebp+0Ch?
```

`[EBP+0Ch]` is the second parameter...

```
add eax, [ebp+10h] //What's ebp+10h
```

`[EBP+10h]` is the third parameter.

So the following line copies `EAX` to the 32-bit value on the stack. Which is `ECX`, which was `PUSH`'d to the stack above.

```
mov [ebp-4], eax   //What's ebp-4
```

Copying back the `ECX` local variable with the following line is quite useless...

```
mov eax, [ebp-4]
```

Now the *Stack Frame* is restored by copying `EBP` back to `ESP`.

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

The following line just does a *32-bit near return* to the caller:

```
retn
```

I assume this explains the function of this subroutine quite well.

Comment: For a downward growing stack it is wrong to write *On entry : ESP = x...After PUSH EBP : ESP = x+4*

Comment: *Then EBP is set to : ESP = x+4 ( = return address +4)* I can't make head nor tail about this sentence!

Comment: @SepRoland: Your right, of course. I fixed that mistake and added some further explanation.

Comment: *Because EBP still points to the stack position when calling this function plus 4* This line still refers to the opposite sense. Write *minus* or try to re-phrase it entirely.

Comment: @SepRoland: I changed it to minus - I missed that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I'll comment each line with what it does:

```
push ebp           //Saves EBP
mov ebp, esp       //Establishes a pointer
push ecx           //Creates local storage
mov eax, [ebp+8]   //This retrieves the 1st parameter
add eax, [ebp+0Ch] //This retrieves the 2nd parameter
add eax, [ebp+10h] //This retrieves the 3rd parameter
mov [ebp-4], eax   //This holds the original ECX, now overwritten by the sum of all 3 parameters
mov eax, [ebp-4]   //This sum is the final result in EAX
mov esp, ebp       //Forgets about the local storage
pop ebp            //Restores EBP
retn               //Returns
```

The use of `push ecx` to create local storage gives a shorter program.
 Another way to do it is `sub esp,4`

So the ultimate goal of this piece of code is to calculate the sum of 3 numbers.

Comment: Sometimes less is more.